# Java interface: Can an interface be used in a Linked list?

Tags: java, interface, linked-list

I am just starting out with java and I was wondering if any one could tell me is there a way to use an interface in a linkedlist. I have an interface called Question. I implement two classes from it: 1) MCQ 2) TrueFalse. I want a list of Question interface so that I can have random MCQs and TrueFalse in my list. Is it possible in Java? This is what I have go so far:

```
private static List<Question> Questions; //declaring in a class

Questions = new LinkedList<Question>(); //creating a linkedlist
```

And then simple adding MCQ's and TrueFalse to it.

Comment: What error did you get? It looks fine to me, I suggest you try it.

Comment: No error. Was just clearing up a concept. Thanks :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong.

Comment: As for concepts, Java guidelines state that field/variable names start with lowercase letter.

Comment: Not only is using an interface correct, it is a best practice, because it makes testing easier, i.e. you can test with "mock objects" that use that interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you write is true and valid.

```
questions = new LinkedList<Question>(); //creating a linkedlist
```

That accepts all type of `Question` objects. To add MCQ's to it, the only rule is your `MCQ` and `TrueFalse` must implement `Question` interface. If you are already doing it you are fine.

But be careful about accessing them. Since you are getting randomly, you never know which object you are getting back. If you assign a MCQ to `TrueFalse`, `ClassCastException` will occur. To avoid such situations, always use it's type (Question).

Comment: Don't downcast if you can help it. It's a code smell. Hence, my answer mentions adding enough methods in the interface to allow the type-specific operations to be done without downcasting.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I am adding the line `To avoid such situations, always use it's type (Question)`

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I didn't suggest casting here. ::::)

Comment: The compiler won't let you assign a `Question` to a `MCQ` or `TrueFalse` without downcasting; so if you don't downcast, a `ClassCastException` won't result. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use interfaces as the type argument to a linked list.

You should define enough methods in the interface to be able to handle all the useful functionality for your MCQs and TrueFalses, without having to downcast.